# HasOne showing either "null" or "Undefined property: Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Relations\\HasOne"

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-one, laravel-relations

I'm trying to use `hasOne` to return a single value within my data set, however I can't seem to return the single column as a value without returning the full object.

What the object looks like when returned when you just return `hasOne`:

```
protected $with = ["steps"];

public function steps() {
    return $this->hasOne("App\Compares\ComparesSteps", "compare_id", "id");
}
```

Result of just using hasOne as the default object:

```
array:21 [
  "id" => 5887894545
  "steps" => array:5 [
    "id" => 21
    "compare_id" => 588789
    "steps" => array:12 [
      0 => 1
      1 => 2
      2 => 3
      3 => 4
      4 => 13
      5 => 6
      6 => 7
      7 => 17
      8 => 8
      9 => 9
      10 => 10
      11 => 12
    ]
    "created_at" => "2021-10-05 08:48:44"
    "updated_at" => "2021-10-05 08:48:44"
  ]
  "created_at" => "2021-10-05 08:48:43"
  "updated_at" => "2021-10-05 08:48:43"
  "expired_at" => "2021-10-09 08:48:43"
  "booked" => 0
  "reference" => null
  "utm" => ""
  "updates" => []
]
```

Returns `null`:

```
   array:21 [
      "id" => 5887894545
      "steps" => null
      "created_at" => "2021-10-05 08:48:43"
      "updated_at" => "2021-10-05 08:48:43"
      "expired_at" => "2021-10-09 08:48:43"
      "booked" => 0
      "reference" => null
      "utm" => ""
      "updates" => []
    ]
```

Returns `Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on array`:

```
public function steps() {
    return $this->hasOne("App\Compares\ComparesSteps", "compare_id", "id")->value("steps");
}
```

Returns `Undefined property: Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Relations\\HasOne::$steps`:

```
public function steps() {
    return $this->hasOne("App\Compares\ComparesSteps", "compare_id", "id")->steps;
}
```

Expected Result:

```
   array:21 [
      "id" => 5887894545
      "steps" => array:12 [
          0 => 1
          1 => 2
          2 => 3
          3 => 4
          4 => 13
          5 => 6
          6 => 7
          7 => 17
          8 => 8
          9 => 9
          10 => 10
          11 => 12
      ]
      "created_at" => "2021-10-05 08:48:43"
      "updated_at" => "2021-10-05 08:48:43"
      "expired_at" => "2021-10-09 08:48:43"
      "booked" => 0
      "reference" => null
      "utm" => ""
      "updates" => []
    ]
```

**Update based on conversation in comments with @MaartenDev**

I want to append the `$model->steps->steps` to `$model->steps` when the model gets called. As I'm updating database tables to split certain data into tables and want to keep the structure of the data the same when calling the model.

e.g. if you was using `getUserCountAttribute` you can easily return just the number by doing `hasMany()->Count()`.

So i'm wanting to append the `steps` array to the `steps` property when the model is called.

Comment: Try with `->steps();`

Comment: @DimitriMostrey - That gives the following `Call to undefined relationship`

Comment: Please add an example how you are trying to accessthe relationship

Comment: @MaartenDev the example is already there it's in the first block of code `protected $with = ["steps"];` It accesses the relationship by default when calling my model `Steps::where("id", 200")->first();`

Comment: @MaartenDev I've also tried with appending attribute with the method of doing `getStepsAttribute()`

Comment: What part fails if you use `return $this->hasOne("App\Compares\ComparesSteps", "compare_id", "id");`? You could then access it using `$model->steps->steps` right?

Comment: @MaartenDev i've updated the question to explain it bit better, please read the part under `Update`

Comment: Would this be an option: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models

Comment: @MaartenDev This wouldn't work as it requires all new columns to be added e.g. `columnname_type` and `columnname_id`. `_id` is fine but the `_type` is pointless to add to all the tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would using a custom getter that uses the `steps` relation be an option? You could preload the values using `$appends`.

```
class Model {
    protected $appends = ["steps"];
    protected $hidden = ['stepsRelation']

    public function getStepsAttribute()
    {
        return $this->stepsRelation->steps;
    }
    
    private function stepsRelation() {
        return $this->hasOne("App\Compares\ComparesSteps", "compare_id", "id");
    }
}
```

Checkout the [Laravel docs on appends](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json).

Comment: How does the `stepsRelation` access the `getStepsAttribute` without it being called and i've just tried this. This doesn't seem to pick up the `getStepsAttribute` and only called the `stepsRelation` due to the `$with = ["stepsRelation"]`. You have to set `$appends` for the getter method to work

Comment: You invoke the `steps` attribute directly instead of using the relation. Does it work when you access steps using `$model->steps`?

Comment: I've got it to work with the following `protected $appends = ['steps'];`. So instead of the `$with` used `$appends`

Comment: Great! I merged your edit with mine, good luck :)

Comment: Is there a way to hide the `stepsRelation` from showing in the returned data?

Comment: You could try making the relation method private or add it to `$hidden = ['stepsRelation']` in your model

Comment: Managed to do it with `$hidden`